# Using Kibana after shield license expired

Tags: logstash, kibana, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-shield

Is there a way to use Kibana 4 after shield license expired?

After read shield documentation, I see the next paragraph:

> When the license for Shield is expired, Shield will block requests to
>   the cluster health, cluster stats, and index stats APIs. Calls to
>   these APIs will fail with a LicenseExpiredException, and will return
>   HTTP status code 401. By disabling only these APIs, any automated
>   cluster monitoring should detect the license failure, while users of
>   the cluster should not be immediately impacted. It is not recommended
>   to run for any length of time with a disabled Shield license; cluster
>   health and stats APIs are critical for monitoring and management of an
>   Elasticsearch cluster.

What are the steps to disable in Kibana 4 the health and stats APIs for monitoring? I only need to access data of the index...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shield is a commercial plugin, so you should buy a license. Please see https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions for more details.